# "find / d" without listing all directories

Tags: bash, unix

I just tried to use `find / d <directory>` in our university server to locate a package that I want to use, and it ended up listing all of the directories in the entire server, from the most basal through all of the open directories of everybody, etc. as it searched. Is there any way to search for directories without the "verbose" mode of thousands upon thousands of directories popping up in my terminal?

Comment: `command>/dev/null`! Just give it a try; it's been long time I've worked on Unix system...

Comment: Better to limit the `find` to select only those directories you are interested in, e.g., `find / -type d -name "*pattern_I_want*"` (you can use specifically exclude `"*pattern_I_dont_want*"` by using the `!` (`-not`) operation). You can further limit by *create*, *access*, or *modify* times or `-newerXY` tests. `find` is made to *find* just what you need -- and it does it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search the entire filesystem for a directory named `mydirectory`, use:

```
find / -type d -name 'mydirectory'
```

That is the slow way, though.  On a well-configured Unix system, there will generally be a `locate` command installed.  `locate` does not have all the fancy features of `find` but, because it works from a database, it will be much faster.  To find, for example, all files in any directory called `mydirectory`, try:

```
locate /mydirectory/
```

Usually, locate's database is updated once a day.  So, if the files or directories you are looking for were installed today, you may need to use `find`.

Comment: Agreed, but the Achilles heel is whether or not `updatedb` had been run since the time the file was created in order for it to be in the database. Most distros I have seen have it at least as a *daily* update. If looking for a file less that 24 hours old, (or the file resides in one of the prune paths not included in the database) you may be stuck with `find`.

Comment: Yes saw that. I was checking the different distros and versions I have. Funny thing is opensuse Leap (at least 42.2) doesn't include mlocate by default. It has in every version of it I have run since SuSE 7.0 pro. Arch includes it by default with base-devel, debian/jesse (raspberry) doesn't. Strange. I thought it was more universal, or maybe I've just been getting stingier with my package selections as I get old...

Comment: Thank you! I must admit that it freaked me out for a moment when I saw thousands of other users' directories being shuttled across my terminal, so I'm glad to know there is a more efficient, less output-heavy way of doing this.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Interesting.  I would have expected it to be commonly installed also.

Comment: @adamrork If you know what the directory that you want is in your home directory, then `find "$HOME" -type d -name 'mydirectory'` or `locate "$HOME/*/mydirectory/*"`